# html navigation dom, how to?

Tags: html, css

Is this the right way to do a nested navigation?

```
 <dl>
  <dt>Struktur</dt>
  <dd>
   <ul id="structure">
    <li><a href="/module/structure/add">Hinzufügen</a></li>
    <li><a href="/module/structure/index">Auflisten</a></li>
   </ul>
  </dd>

  <dt>Nachrichten</dt>
  <dd>
   <ul id="messages">
    <li><a href="/module/messages/add">Schreiben</a></li>
    <li><a href="/module/messages/directory">Ordner</a></li>
    <li><a href="/module/messages/index">Auflisten</a></li>
   </ul>
  </dd>
  </dl>
```

Comment: That depends on what do you mean by "right way".

Comment: I mean do i use the right elements, is it correctly 'marked'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with n1313, it really depends what you mean by "right way".

If you do want a nit-picky answer: Strictly speaking, "Hinzufügen" and "Auflisten" are not the *definition* of "Struktur", so using a `<dl>` list to structure those elements is probably not The Right Way™. A simple nested `<ul>` list might be better.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="parent">Struktur</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this answer.
A unordered list, is the most common way of creating a menu.

Answer (score 0):

semantically, i dont think using a dt tag is correct.
use a h2 or h3 tag instead.

```
<h2>Nachrichten</h2>
<ul id="messages">
    <li><a href="/module/messages/add">Schreiben</a></li>
    <li><a href="/module/messages/directory">Ordner</a></li>
    <li><a href="/module/messages/index">Auflisten</a></li>
</ul>
```

looking at your code, it doesnt seem like you're nesting any of the ul/li items, but the method deceze posted for doing so is correct:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2
      <ul>
         <li>subitem</li>
         <li>subitem 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```